# D1's auto and scope difference in memory allocation

Tags: memory-management, d

D's docs saying that when you use `scope` for local variables, then they will be allocated on stack (even if you're allocating `class` instance). But what about `auto` keyword? Does it guarantee that the instance will be allocated on stack?

1. `void foo() { auto instance = new MyClass();}`
2. `void foo() { scope instance = new MyClass();}`

So can I suggest that this two statements are equal (in terms of allocation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `auto` only infers the type.
There's no point in using `auto` if you want it to be allocated on the stack; that's what `scope` is (was) for.

They've brilliantly (read: not so much) decided to remove `scope`, `delete`, etc. from the language, so it will probably allocate on the heap anyway. Your best bet is to use the function called `scoped` in one of the modules, to allocate on the stack.

Comment: Those removal only affects D2. D1 will still have `scope` and `delete` no matter what. (In D2 `scope` will be replaced by a library features and `delete` will be replaced by `clear()`.)

Comment: @KennyTM: Good point -- I didn't notice D1 in the title, since it wasn't in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question: in D1 those two statements are not equal. First one allocates on the heap, second one is (supposed) to allocate on the stack.